# How do I get the tweet someone is mentioning my bot's username in reply to with Tweepy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I am trying to create a Twitter bot using Tweepy that replies to mentions but needs to process the tweet the mention is replying to. I have everything else figured out except how to get the tweet the mention is replying to. I have looked through the documentation several times and have been unable to find a way to do this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: show minimal working code which we could simply copy and run.

Answer (score 1):

to have your bot reply to a user's screen_name is what I think is what you are asking here. You need to have:

1. class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener)
2. inside the class, function on_status(self, status) and on_error(self, status_code)

   ```
    class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
          def on_status(self, status):
              name = status.user.screen_name
              id_str = status.id_str

              message = " // < message > //"
              reply_tweet = "@" + str(name) + " " + message

              api.update_status(reply_tweet, in_reply_to_status_id= id_str)
              print(" <tweet received> " + status.text)
              print(" tweet sent back > " + reply_tweet)

         def on_error(self, status_code):
             if status_code == 420:
                print("rate limit reached") 
                return False
   ```

i would suggest having a timer in a while loop function as to avoid rate limits